# Vue: delete an item from array when it is passed as a prop to a component?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I am very new to Vue.js.

I first searched for how to do this (removing an element from an array, given just the element in the array), but all I found was references to either the `delete` method or calling `slice` on the list... which of course is relevant, but does not answer my question.

I made a fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/SumNeuron/d2a9j2mh/

Ideally, I want to click delete to remove the tab and the tab pane.

Is there a way to do this without passing the list as a prop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this your expectation: https://jsfiddle.net/ittus/Lost5djd/ ?

I emit event when click remove button

```
  methods: {
    remove: function() {
      console.log(this, this.tab)
      this.$emit('remove', this.index)
    }
  }
```

and listen to it on parent component

```
  methods: {
    onRemove(index) {
      this.groups =  [
       ...this.groups.slice(0, index),
       ...this.groups.slice(index + 1)
     ]
    }
  }
```

If each tab have an `id`, solution will be more elegant.

Comment: this is my expectation. I started Vue this morning. Is my approach thus far ok, or do you have any other recommendations for what I have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

By emitting an event from the component to the parent. 
I have forked the code here is the link 
https://jsfiddle.net/gfa3psg1 .

creating an emitter

```
var __emiter = new Vue();
```

Emit from button

```
__emiter.$emit('deleteTab', this.tab);
```

catch from app

```
__emiter.$on('deleteTab', (group) => {
        this.groups = this.groups.filter(function(_group) {
                return _group.title !== group.title;
                });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I forked your jsfiddle with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/budgw/eyxppq4j/1/

The simpliest way I think is to use an event on the `remove` button. This event carry the tab object then your parent component (your Vue application here) listen to this event and remove the tab from the list.

I like to think about events and props like this : events are a way to give data to parent component while props give data to children.

Comment: oops i forgot to click on the update button ;-), I edited my answer with the correct link.